# Javascript and ArcGIS : displaying selected service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arcgis

I have a bit of javascript that I am trying to tweak to get working for a ArcGIS web app.

I have an array of a couple services in config.json:

```
    {
      "mapServices":[{
        "id":"one",
        "url":"http://mysrv:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FOLDER/srv_one/MapServer",
        "name":"Service One",
        "type":"dynamic"
      },
      {
        "id":"two",
        "url":"http://mysrv:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FOLDER/srv_two/MapServer",
        "name":"Service Two",
        "type":"dynamic"
      }
    ]
    }
```

The following javascript adds all layers in all services to the map :

```
'use strict';
mapAppControllers.controller('MapController', function($scope, $http) {
    var me=$scope;
    $scope.$parent.mapController=$scope;
    var Dynamic,Tile;

    angular.extend($scope,{
        onReady:function(){
            var lArgs=arguments;
            $http.get('resources/config.json').then(function(pResponse){
                me.config=pResponse.data;
                me.init.apply(me,lArgs);
            });
        },
        addLayer:function(pMapService,pCallback){
            var lMapService;
            if(pMapService.type=='dynamic'){
                lMapService=new Dynamic(pMapService.url,pMapService);
            }else if(pMapService.type=='tile'){
                lMapService=new Tile(pMapService.url,pMapService);
            }
            if(lMapService){
                lMapService=me.map.addLayer(lMapService);
                lMapService.on('load',function(){
                    pCallback(lMapService);
                });
            }else{
                pCallback();
            }
        },
        init:function(Map,Dom,Navigation,Draw,ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,IdentifyParameters,
                      IdentifyResult,IdentifyTask,GraphicsLayer,InfoWindow){

            Dynamic=ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;
            me.map = new Map("mapDiv");

            var lIndex=0;
            var lCallback=function(pMapService){
                me.config.mapServices[lIndex].service=pMapService;
                lIndex++;
                if(lIndex==me.config.mapServices.length){
                    me.layer=pMapService;
                    me.graphicsLayer=me.map.addLayer(new GraphicsLayer({id:'resultsGL'}));
                    me.toolbarScope.init(Navigation,Draw,me.map);
                    me.indentifyScope.init(IdentifyParameters,IdentifyResult,IdentifyTask,me.map,me.layer);
                    me.resultsScope.init(me.map,me.layer,me.graphicsLayer);
                    me.mapServiceScope.init(me.config.mapServices);
                    return;
                }
                me.addLayer(me.config.mapServices[lIndex],lCallback);
            };

            me.addLayer(me.config.mapServices[lIndex],lCallback);
        }
    });
});
```

I have another controller that allows users to choose a service by name :

```
'use strict';
mapAppControllers.controller('MapServiceController', function($scope,$rootScope,$http) {
    var me=$scope;
    $rootScope.mapServiceScope=$scope;
    angular.extend($scope,{
        layers: [],
        layersOptions:{'visible':true,'show':true,'all':true},
        setLayers:function(pLayerInfos){
            me.layers.splice(3);
            pLayerInfos.forEach(function(pLayerInfo){
                if(pLayerInfo.subLayerIds==null){
                    me.layers.push(pLayerInfo);
                }
            });

            me.serviceSelected=me.services[0].name;
            me.serviceSelectedModel=me.services[0];
            me.layerSelected=me.layers[0].name;
            me.layerSelectedModel=me.layers[0];
        },
        init:function(pMapServices){
            me.services=pMapServices;
            var IdParams=require("esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters");
            me.layers=[{
                id:IdParams.LAYER_OPTION_VISIBLE,
                name:'Les couches visibles',
                isOption:true
            },{
                id:IdParams.LAYER_OPTION_ALL,
                name:'Toutes les couches',
                isOption:true
            },{
                id:IdParams.LAYER_OPTION_TOP,
                name:'La couche supérieur',
                isOption:true
            }];
            me.setLayers(me.services[0].service.layerInfos);
            me.$digest()
        },
        onLayerSelect:function($model){
            me.layerSelectedModel=$model;
        },
        onServiceSelect:function($model){
            me.serviceSelectedModel=$model;
        }
    });
}).filter('BoldLayersOptions',['$sce',function($sce){
    var lLayersOptions={'visible':true,'top':true,'all':true};

    return function(pMatch, pObject) {
        if(pObject.model.id in lLayersOptions){
            pMatch=$sce.trustAsHtml('<b><u style="cursor:pointer">'+pMatch+'</u></b>');
        }
        return pMatch;
    };
}]);
```

I tried tweaking the first controller in this way, but the user selection variable is undefined at this time. Any ideas how to access the user choice at this point?

```
if(pMapService.type=='dynamic' && pMapService.name == me.serviceSelected){
                    lMapService=new Dynamic(pMapService.url,pMapService);
                }
```

I'm attempting to use the ArcGIS Javascript API for the first time and am very new to Javascript.